# FFPMEG: stream local video to UDP address, make client aware about video length and current frame time offset (make stream seekable?)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, transcoding

Just started to use FFMPEG. This is a really great library which is capable of video life transcoding and streaming.

I use following commands to transcode and stream local video file to UDP address:
ffmpeg  -y -re -i inputvideo.mpeg2  -vsync 1 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 1600k -r 15 -crf 20 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -strict -2 -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.30:1234

It works smooth. I can open this udp address in VLC player and play life stream.

Does anybody know how to make client aware about video duration and current time stamp?

Ideally would be nice to make stream seekable, as far as I understand it is not possible, but at least I would like to tell VLC client the total duration of the video and current frame time stamp, so it could show the progress.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, maybe ask on the VLC forum and/or ffmpeg-uesr ML GL!

Comment: Just recently installed Plex Media Server and discovered that it uses ffmpeg to turn file into the HSL stream! And HTML client which is JWPlayer can pickup the stream, shows the duration and allows to seek the video!!!

Comment: Actually in the latest Plex Media Server version ffmpeg has been replaced with universal transcoder which does the same things and even better! Is it possible to use it without Plex Media Server?